# Create multiple lists from a list by breaking it before each occurrence of given value

Tags: python

I'm trying to create multiple lists from the list below:

```
lst=[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
```

Condition: Break before the "1" in the list and create a new list. Like shown below:

```
lst1= [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]

lst2= [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]

lst3= [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., ]

lst4=[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0., 0.]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

List comp solution:

```
>>> [(a := [x]) for x in lst if x or a.append(x)]
[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

Pre-Python-3.8 version:

```
>>> [a for x in lst if x or a.append(x) for a in [[x]]]
[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

(This is also a bit cleaner, as `a` only exists during the list comp, not afterwards.)

Comment: fyi python 3.8+ only

Comment: @DerekEden Added a pre-3.8 version.

Answer (score 2):

```
list_number = []
lst=[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
for x in lst:
    if x==1:
        list_number.append([1])
    else:
        list_number[-1].append(x)

lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4, lst5, lst6 = list_number
```

Easy solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use np.array and np.where

```
lst=[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]

import numpy as np
Aux = np.array(lst + [1.])
Ones = np.where(Aux==1.)[0]

result = [ list(Aux[Ones[i]:Ones[i+1]]) for i in range(len(Ones)-1)]
print(result)

Out >>> [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
        [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
        [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
        [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

could do something like this:

```
def group(l, key=1, inner=[]):
    out = []
    for i, ele in enumerate(l):
        if ele == key:
            if i > 0:
                out.append(inner)
            inner = [ele]
        else:
            inner.append(ele)
    out.append(inner)
    return out

print(group(lst))

[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

essentially all it's doing is going through the list and appending each element to a inner list, when it reaches a 1 it will append the inner list to the out list then clear/restart the inner list..and repeats

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
lst=[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
new_lst=[]
for i in lst:
     if i == 1:
          new_lst.append([])
     new_lst[-1].append(i)
     
#########print 
for i in new_lst:
     print(i)
```

**Output**

```
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy to understand function that does what you want:

```py
def split_by(lst, delim):
  lists = []

  lists_idx = -1
  for i in lst:
    if i == delim:
      lists.append([delim])
      lists_idx+=1
    else:
      lists[lists_idx].append(i)

  return lists

lst=[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]

lists = split_by(lst, 1.)

for n, i in enumerate(lists):
  print(n+1,i)
```